# Unit test views - best practice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, testing

Can anyone share experience with unit testing views? I read a lot of tutorials about how to do unit testing with views, but everything has some drawbacks.

I came along with the following approach. It works, but I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this. There are also some drawbacks, which I'll explain later on. I'm also doing E2E tests with protractor, but they are always slow, and therefore I limit them to a minimum.

This is my controller. It has two variables bound to its `$scope` which are used in the view:

```
// test_ctrl.js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('TestCtrl', ["$rootScope", "$scope", function ($rootScope, $scope) {
    $scope.bar = "TEST";
    $scope.jobs = [
      {name: "cook"}
    ];
  }]);
```

The view takes the `$scope.bar` into a `<span>` and the `$scope.jobs` array into an `ng-repeat` directive:

```
<!-- test.html the view for this controller -->
<span>
  Bar is {{bar || "NOT SET"}}
</span>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="job in jobs">{{job.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

And this is the test:

```
describe('Controller: TestCtrl', function () {
  beforeEach(module('templates'));
  beforeEach(module('app'));

  var TestCtrl, $rootScope, $compile, createController, view, $scope;
  beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $templateCache, _$rootScope_, _$compile_, _$httpBackend_) {
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    $compile = _$compile_;

    createController = function() {
      var html = $templateCache.get('views/test.html');
      TestCtrl = $controller('TestCtrl', { $scope: $scope, $rootScope: $rootScope });
      view = $compile(angular.element(html))($scope);
      $scope.$digest();
    };
  }));

  it('should test the view', function() {
    createController();
    expect(view.find("li").length).toEqual(1)
    console.log($scope.jobs)
  });
});
```

In the `beforeEach` function, I'll set up the controller. The `createController` function (which is called from the tests itself) takes a view out of the `$templateCache`, creates a controller with it's own `$scope`, then it compiles the template and triggers a `$digest`.

The template cache is prefilled with karmas preprocessor ng-html2js

```
// karma.conf.js
...
preprocessors: {
  'app/views/*.html': 'ng-html2js'
}
...
```

With this approach, I have a little problem, and some questions:

**1. Additional $$hashKey keys in my objects from `ng-repeat`**

The `expect($scope.jobs).toEqual([{name: "cook"}]);` in my test throws an error:

```
Expected [ { name : 'cook', $$hashKey : '009' } ] to equal [ { name : 'cook' } ]
```

I know that `ng-repeat` adds these keys, but this is silly to test. The only way around I can think of is separating the controller tests and the view tests. But when I check the `jobs` array inside my controller, the `$$hashKey` is not present. Any ideas, why this is happening?

**2. $scope problem**

When I tried this for the first time, I only had my local scope defined as `$scope={}` and not `$scope = $rootScope.$new()`, as I have done in my other controller tests. But with just a plain object as a local scope, I wasn't able to compile it (`$compile(angular.element(html))($scope);` throwed an error).

I also thought if it is a good idea to pass the `$rootScope` itself as the current local scope for the controller. Is this a good approach? Or are there any drawbacks, I haven't seen yet?

**3. Best practices**

I would be very happy to know, how everyone else is doing unit tests in AngularJS. I think views have to be tested, because with all the angular directives, there lies a lot of logic in them, which I would be glad to see waterproofed ;)

Comment: It might be worth noting that using the _track by_ expression in the ng-repeat directive might help you get rid of the hashkeys (and speed up your lookups). See http://www.codelord.net/2014/04/15/improving-ng-repeat-performance-with-track-by/

Comment: This has nothing to do with unit testing, but after looking at the sample controller I want to leave this comment here for the erudition of the passing programmer: its a good practice to not pollute the `$scope` with controller's local variables. Better use `this.bar = "TEST"`, and reference it in the view with `ng-controller="TestCtrl as ctrl"` and `ctrl.bar`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think that what you're doing is a great way to unit test views. The code in your question is a good recipe for someone looking to unit test views.

---

### 1. ng-repeat $$hashKey

Don't worry about the data. Instead, test the result of various operations, because that's what you really care about at the end of the day. So, use [jasmine-jquery](https://github.com/velesin/jasmine-jquery) to verify the state of the DOM after creation of the controller, and after simulated `click()`s, etc.

---

### 2. $scope = $rootScope.$new() ain't no problem

`$rootScope` is an instance of **Scope**, while `$rootScope.$new()` creates an instance of **ChildScope**. Testing with an instance of **ChildScope** is technically more correct because in production, controller scopes are instances of **ChildScope** as well.

BTW, the same goes for unit testing directives that create isolated scopes. When you `$compile` your directive with an instance of **ChildScope** an isolated scope will be created automatically(which is an instance of **Scope**). You can access that isolated scope with `element.isolateScope()`

```
// decalare these variable here so we have access to them inside our tests
var element, $scope, isolateScope;

beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {
  var html = '<div my-directive></div>';

  // this scope is an instance of ChildScope
  $scope = $rootScope.$new();

  element = angular.element(html);   
  $compile(element)($scope);
  $scope.$digest();

  // this scope is an instance of Scope
  isolateScope = element.isolateScope(); 
}));
```

---

### 3. +1 Testing Views

Some people say test views with Protractor. Protractor is great when you want to test the entire stack: front end to back end. However, Protractor is slow, and unit testing is fast. That's why it makes sense to test your views and directives with unit tests by mocking out any part of the application that relies on the back-end.

Directives are highly unit testable. Controllers less so. Controllers can have a lot of moving parts and this can make them more difficult to test. For this reason, I am in favor of creating directives often. The result is more modular code that's easier to test.