# How to test controller with template provided by state from ui-router

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angular-ui-router

Configuration for ui router:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('search', {
            url: '/search',
            views: {
                content: {
                    templateUrl: 'scripts/search/search-content.html',
                    controller: 'SearchController'
                }
            }
        })
```

What is the right way for testing controller functionality and template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found explanation about how to testing routes and page view from ng-book:

> **Testing Page Content**
>
> Unit testing content in the browser won’t give us much insight into
>   the state of the application, as we don’t have direct access to
>   browser content in unit testing. **We can confirm that the controllers
>   are executing the expected functions and set assertions that confirm
>   the content will load**, which we will cover in depth.

I can assume that the main goal is testing router controller, without template.

Another suggestion i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23083645/unit-test-views-best-practice)